# Windows Azure Error

Tags: windows, azure, azure-storage

I´m getting this error in Windows Azure..

The key was wrong! Thx a lot! but now i'm getting this error: The table specified does not exist.

The initial code was not made by me...I need to clear up the code...

I have not found where the table is determined...

Ps.: sorry for the confuse question...This is all that I know about the problem..

Comment: what code was executing at the time, this could be as simple as an incorrect storage account key specified in a table query request. Is it persistent, or does it work after executing again?

Comment: The key was wrong! Thx a lot! but now i'm getting this error: The table specified does not exist.